# How to send userId to the Codeigniter Controller through Angular View state

Tags: php, codeigniter, angularjs

I want the state to send userID to the codeigniter controller, but i am not sure that how to do that?

```
    .state('users.edit', {
                // parent: 'contacts',
                url: '/{userId}/edit',
//                resolve: {
//                    something:
//                        [        '$timeout', '$stateParams',
//                            function ($timeout,   $stateParams) {
//                                return $timeout(function () { return "Asynchronously resolved data (" + $stateParams.contactId + ")" }, 10);
//                            }],
//                },
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: BASE_URL + 'index.php/users/profile_edit/'
//                        controller:
//                            [        '$scope', '$stateParams', 'something',
//                                function ($scope,   $stateParams,   something) {
//                                    $scope.something = something;
//                                    $scope.contact = findById($scope.users, $stateParams.userId);
//                                }]
                    },
```

e-g if a user goes to this link

```
url#/users/3/edit
```

then the above state will be called for `url: '/{userId}/edit'`
and here i want it to load templateurl on base of {userId}

```
templateUrl: BASE_URL + 'index.php/users/profile_edit/'
```

---

i tried it both like this

```
templateUrl: BASE_URL + 'index.php/users/profile_edit/' + {userId}
```

and like this.

```
templateUrl: BASE_URL + 'index.php/users/profile_edit/{userId}/'
```

can anyone solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this `js` in the same `php page` then you can write something like this:

```
templateUrl: BASE_URL + 'index.php/users/profile_edit/<?=userId?>'
```

Otherwise if its on a separate `js` file, just define in your header:

```
var UserId = '<?=userId?>';
```

Then use the variable `UserId` in your `js` file like this:

```
templateUrl: BASE_URL + 'index.php/users/profile_edit/'+userId
```